# How to continue using GNOME2 with Ubuntu or a derived distribution?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-unity, desktop-environments

I am currently using Ubuntu 11.04 with GNOME2 instead of the new default, Unity.

I heard that in a newer Ubuntu version there is no GNOME2 aka Ubuntu classic desktop anymore.

Which Linux distribution will continue to include or support GNOME2, its start menu, it's panel, the task switch and the general look and feel?

People I know switched to KDE instead. But I really like GNOME and want to stick to it.

Comment: Presumably you can [get GNOME 2 back](http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/linux-distributions/linux-distributions4-ubuntu/1643-how-to-move-back-from-unity-to-gnome2-classic-in-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal). Also, don't listen to the KDE people - they're doing it because Linus likes it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can install MATE** (MATE is a fork of Gnome 2)

Which distributions provide **MATE**?

- **[Linux Mint](http://linuxmint.com/)** (MATE is installed by default in the main DVD edition)

Which distributions is MATE packaged for?

- **[Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org/)** (MATE is available to users via [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MATE))
- **[Linux Mint](http://linuxmint.com/)** (MATE is available to users via the [Linux Mint repositories](http://packages.linuxmint.com/list.php?release=Lisa#import))
- **[Debian](http://www.debian.org/) / [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/)** (MATE is currently available to users via the [tridex repository](http://mate.karapetsas.com/))

**From:** [Mate-Desktop.org](http://mate-desktop.org/)

**Note:** I did not had a good experience installing it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

[Linux Mint](http://linuxmint.com/) is a Ubuntu derivative that is currently continuing with Gnome 2.  They also have a project in place to address some of the concerns that Gnome users have with Gnome 3, and are making a more Gnome2y version of it.

Comment: Well, not quite: *> Linux Mint 12 'Lisa' will come with its own customized desktop and it will be based on Gnome 3. The core desktop will be based on a series of Gnome Shell extensions called 'MGSE' (Mint Gnome Shell Extensions) that will provide a layer on top of Gnome 3. MGSE also includes additional extensions such as a media player indicator, and multiple enhancements to Gnome 3. Thus Linux Mint 12 will be more like a hybrid desktop balancing traditional desktop and new modern technologies.* See here for more: http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=1851

Answer (score 0):

The Mint Gnome Shell Extensions (MGSE) can be installed in Ubuntu.

This project was renamed to [Cinnamon](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/cinnamon-project-keeps-gnome-2-style-desktop-alive/) which can be easily installed via a PPA.